# Eclipse Plugins: Find the active handlers for a given command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

To learn more about Eclipse plugin development, it would be cool if I could read the implementation code for some of the `Handler` classes that support the built in Eclipse commands.

How I can find out the currently active handler class(es) for a specific command, such as for example `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type`, in my current Eclipse instance? If this isn't possible, what's the best way in general to see what type of code implements that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the handler for a built-in function like "Open Type", one can simply look at the source code for the appropriate Eclipse project plugin. For JDT, this is located at http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git. The plugin.xml file at the root of the project specifies how commands are handled.

The Open Type command, for example, is handled by an Action, specifically OpenTypeAction in package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.